# unsuccessful to demonstrate concurrent increment/decrement

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I've started this week with Java threads and concurrence; and I need some help with the next code that I've implemented using `Thread` instead `Runnable`:

**Class**

```
package hilos;

public class Hilo extends Thread {

//Atributos

public static int concurso = 0;
private int veces;
private boolean incrementoDecremento;

//Método constructor

public Hilo(boolean inc, int numeroVeces){

    this.incrementoDecremento = inc;
    this.veces = numeroVeces;
}

//Método run

@Override

public void run(){

    for(int i = 0; i < this.veces; i++){    

        if(this.incrementoDecremento == true){

            concurso++;
            System.out.println("La variable introducida es: " + concurso);

        }else{

            concurso--;
            System.out.println("La variable introducida es: " + concurso);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Main**

```
package hilos;

public class Usa_Hilos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int prueba = 5;
    Hilo positivo = new Hilo(true, prueba);
    Hilo negativo = new Hilo(false, prueba);


    positivo.start();
    negativo.start();

    try{

        positivo.join();
        negativo.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){

        System.out.println("Se ha producido un error.");
    }
}

}
```

My objective is that if I have two tasks using the same value, both start incrementing and decrementing it randomly, so basically it will result in a random value determinated by the variable `prueba` which is located in the `Main` class.

The problem is that for some reason, I keep testing again and again and my final result is always a zero. I have no problems implementing this with `synchronized` statement and `Runnable`, but it's impossible for me using `Thread`.

Comment: If you increment a variable 5 times and decrement it 5 times it will be the same value than the beginning (which was 0). You dont see any ill effects of raceconditions in your example, so it matches perectly out. If you test for larger counts or possibly with bigger threads it might turn out not to sum up to 0 as you are not using atomic operations.

Comment: You have a number of issues. Some serious and some very serious. First, never `extends Thread` unless you are actually _extending_ the functionally of a `Thread` - use `Runnable` instead. Onto the very serious issues - you have a lot of access to variables with no memory barrier; this is known as a race condition - you need to read up on synchronisation and volatile references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try numbers larger than 5. Your threads are probably running so quickly that the first one finishes before the second starts.

10000 demonstrated the problem fine for me:

```
public class BadThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread( 10000);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(-10000);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(MyThread.shared);
    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {
        public static int shared;
        private int change;

        public MyThread(int change) {
            this.change = change;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (change < 0) {
                change++;
                shared--;
            }
            while (change > 0) {
                change--;
                shared++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
tmp$ javac BadThreads.java && java BadThreads
-8680
```

...so there we successfully demonstrated a concurrency issue. Your runs of only 5 simply got "lucky" -- or unlucky in your case, as you were trying to demonstrate the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static int. Use an AtomicInteger. It was designed for precisely this case.

If you don't want to use that, make `concurso` `volatile`. You're seeing cached values.

Comment: @xFunkyTimes was specifically trying to *create* a concurrency problem, most likely for demonstration purposes (or just their own understanding). But yes, AtomicIntegers are good (if used correctly).

Comment: And after he made the variable volatile what should he do next to actually solve the problem? Because volatile alone isn't enough.